# Three-finger swipe between pages unresponsive

Tags: macos, trackpad

After upgrading to Mountain Lion I'm sometimes having to two-finger scroll up or down at least once before I can three-finger swipe between pages. It's as if I have to "re-activate" the gesture every time I open or switch to another app. After I've done that, it'll work consistently in the app until I switch to another again. I also uninstalled and reinstalled Better Touch Tool and that also seems to make swiping work for a short period of time before it breaks again.

Pretty much exactly as this issue posted below, except in that case the problem resolved with an update or a reboot:

- [Trackpad Gestures - Three-finger swipe unresponsive until I use two-finger scroll (OS X Lion)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51815/)

Would anyone have a solution to this besides Better Touch Tool to solve this on an Macbook Pro (Early 2008)?  I thought the new 10.8.3 update would've solved the issue, but I haven't noticed any changes.

I'm on a Macbook Pro (Early 2008) and wonder if there's a more permanent solution to BTT and this gesture being reliable available?